# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match in conjunction with Apache httpd virtual hosts

Tags: java, apache, ssl, httpclient

I have two app servers alpha and beta. Both are on the same host, both are accessed thru apache httpd with virtual hosts for each app.

`https://alpha` has a certificate with the proper CN set and `https://beta` does as well.  The DNS for each is a CNAME entry to the underlying host.

Our Apache HttpClient based client throws a "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match" exception when accessing `https://beta` indicating that the certificate it is getting is for alpha.

The java keytool command:

`keytool -printcert -sslserver beta`

shows the same problem, returning the certificate for alpha.  The [InstallCert.java](https://github.com/elerch/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java) utility shows the correct certificate for beta.

Currently, we think the best solution is to replace the CNAME records with A records, but having done this yet due to the lead time involved.  Any suggestions would be (very) welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using a version of Apache HTTPClient which has support for [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Older version like the one often used on Android don't support SNI.

Comment: I looked into it and it appears that the version of Apache HttpComponents in use is one prior to 4.3.2 in which SNI support was added.  The JIRA issue for this discusses the exact problem we're seeing!  Should be an easy fix.  Thanks a ton Steffen!!!